# How can you store an array object in a single reference of Object class?

Tags: java

As far as my understanding goes Object is also a class in java. So,how is it that we can write

```
Object ob = new Integer[2];
```

and not

```
Integer i = new Integer[2];
```

How is it that a single reference `ob` can point to array of Integers but reference of type `Integer` can't?

Comment: `Object` is the mother of all classes -- all other classes inherit from it.  `Integer` and `Integer[]` are two different classes where neither inherits from the other.

Comment: ok that explains it, so basically Integer[2] is treated as a different class:)

Comment: Note that you should say `new Integer[2]` and that creates an array object, which is a subtype of `Object`.

Comment: In Java, array length is not part of the type.  There is no type called `Integer[2]`. The type of arrays of `Integer` objects is written `Integer[]`.

Comment: Yep, `Integer[]` is a distinct class from `Integer`.  The array size is not a part of the class identity, though.  (But also understand that `Integer[][]` is a distinct class from `Integer[]`.)

Comment: (It should be noted that this is one place where Java differs significantly from C, since in C "arrays decay to pointers", but in Java that's not the case.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`JLS#Chapter 10. Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and **may be assigned to variables of type Object** (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.
>
> All the components of an array have the same type, called the component type of the array. **If the component type of an array is T, then the type of the array itself is written T[].**

Comment: thanks this explains a lot:), obviously it was a tough choice to choose the right answer, but the last line in you answer made more sense, thanks all for answering so fast:)

Answer (score 5):

Because every array is an object. So polymorphism rules tell us that `Integer[]` (array of `Integer`) can be stored in an `Object`, but obviously `Integer[]` (array of `Integer`) can not be stored in an `Integer`.

Comment: Your statements are quite confusing. You can store `Integer[2]` in `Integer`. You cannot store `new Integer[2]` in `Integer`.

Comment: @RohitJain what do you mean when you say "You can store Integer[2] in Integer"

Comment: I mean, `Integer[2]` seems like accessing `2nd index` in some array names `Integer`. I know its not possible. But you should edit it to make it more sensible. Just a Suggestion.

Comment: @RohitJain: You're confusing types with expressions. The type of of arrays of `Integer` objects (that is, `Integer[].class`) is distinct from the type of `Integer` objects (that is, `Integer.class`).

Comment: @DanielPryden.. That I know. I'm talking about this: - `Integer[] Integer = new Integer[2];
    System.out.println(Integer[1]);` Now `Integer[1]` is an `Integer` here. That's why I said, writing `new Integer[2]` will be more sensible, as it would mean an array rather than `Integer[2]` that sounds like an `array element`.. Of course that is hardly goind to be noticed.

Comment: @RohitJain: You're focusing on the wrong part of the problem. `new` is superfluous; the problem is that there is no type in Java named `Integer[2]`. If you stick a `new` in front of it, it becomes an *expression* that creates a type, but that doesn't mean that expression is a suitable *name* for the type. The name of the type is `Integer[]`.

Comment: Ah!! Why it's sometimes so hard for me to explain some stuffs. :( Anyways. leave it.

Comment: @RohitJain I fixed it a bit, to make it more clear. It's all about word nuances, I believe :) .

Comment: @SoboLAN.. Yeah. Now its ok. That is what I wanted to say, that was unfortunately stretched into a long discussion. :)

Answer (score 3):

Because every array is a subtype of `Object`. But no array is a subtype of `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the following expression on the `RHS` creates an `array object`: -

```
new Integer[2];
```

So, your reference type on the LHS should be compatible to be able to hold a reference to an array.

Now, since `array` in Java is a subtype of `Object`, so an `Object` type can hold a reference to an array.
But, an `Integer` reference of course cannot point to an `array`.

So,

```
Object ob = new Integer[2]; // is valid. as `Object` type reference can point to an array object
Integer i = new Integer[2]; // is not valid. as `Integer` type reference cannot point to an array object.
```